# Extract first values per 4 rows from pandas dataframe to make a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I used "pandas.read_csv" and the data is like below

```
　　　A　　　　　B　　C　　　　　　　D
00　　2019-2　　3　　7         　　7
01　　2019-1　　3　　3         　　6
02　　2018-4　　3　　4         　　6
03　　2018-3　　3　　5         　　6
04　　2018-2　　3　　6         　　None
05　　2018-1　　3　　None　　      7
06　　2017-4　　3　　5         　　6
07　　2017-3　　3　　4         　　5
08　　2017-2　　3　　3         　　5
09　　2017-1　　3　　4         　　5
10　　2016-4　　3　　3         　　4
11　　2016-3　　3　　2         　　4
12　　2016-2　　4　　5         　　5
13　　2016-1　　4　　3         　　7
14　　2015-4　　4　　4         　　11
15　　2015-3　　4　　2         　　5
16　　2015-2　　4　　None　　  　　5
17　　2015-1　　3　　1         　　None
```

How could I extract the first data per 4 rows to a new dataframe?
it has 18 rows. And 18 cannot be divided by 4, so I want to throw row16,row17

The result that i want is like this

```
　　　A　　　　　B　　C　　　　　　　D
00　　2019-2　　3　　7         　　7
04　　2018-2　　3　　6         　　0
08　　2017-2　　3　　3         　　5
12　　2016-2　　4　　5         　　5
```

And i just tried

```
N = 4

#first remove last rows if remainders
df = df.iloc[:len(df) // N * N]

#convert to numeric
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['C'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
df['B'] = pd.to_numeric(df['C'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
df['C'] = pd.to_numeric(df['C'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
df['D'] = pd.to_numeric(df['C'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```

Comment: Why don't you want row 16?

Comment: I just want first data "per 4 rows"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC we can slice the df before we `groupby`

```
n=(len(df)//4)*4
df=df.iloc[:n, :].groupby(np.arange(n) // 4).head(1).replace('None',0)
Out[13]: 
         A  B  C  D
0   2019-2  3  7  7
4   2018-2  3  6  0
8   2017-2  3  3  5
12  2016-2  4  5  5
```

Comment: How could i reindex like this: 0 4 8 12 -> 0 1 2 3

Comment: `df.reset_index(drop=True)`
Please also consult the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index).

Comment: @MonoNeuElogy df=df.reset_index(drop=True)

Answer (score 1):

You can select multiple rows by providing a list for `iloc`. So

```
df.iloc[[i * n for i in range(len(df) // n)]].replace('None',0)
```

should do it, even if the length of `df` is a multiple of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
    df.iloc[df.index[::4]].fillna(0)[:-1]
```

Output:

```
0           A  B  C     D
index                    
00     2019-2  3  7     7
04     2018-2  3  6     0
08     2017-2  3  3     5
12     2016-2  4  5     5
```

Comment: This will leave out the last valid row iff the length is divisible by 4. E.g. row `08` would be missing if 12 rows exist (`00`-`11`).

Answer (score 0):

I loop through the `groupby` and grab the first row via `itertuples` if the length of the group is equal to 4.

```
m = np.arange(len(df)) // 4
tups = [
    next(d.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
    for _, d in df.replace('None', 0).groupby(m)
    if len(d) == 4
]
pd.DataFrame(tups, columns=df.columns)

        A  B  C  D
0  2019-2  3  7  7
1  2018-2  3  6  0
2  2017-2  3  3  5
3  2016-2  4  5  5
```